# copy the filtered data to a new workbook (create new one at he same time) and save the name as the filter value in Pivot

Tags: python, excel, vba, pivot

I have an Excel file,created Pivot and Two filter (name and date)when am filtering by name

I would like to filter each name and create a new workbook with that name(filtername) and paste the filtered data into it.At a time only one name should be in the filter

I tried this Code.

```vb
Sub arcpivot3()
    Dim myPivotField As PivotField
    Dim filterValue As String
    Dim vendorname As String
    Dim myString As String
    Dim a As String
    Dim k As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim wkb As Workbook

    Dim fp As Worksheet
    Dim vr As Worksheet
    Dim temp, ALastRow, BLastRow As Integer
    Dim VendorNamesArray(100) As String
    Dim VendorNames(1000) As String

    Set fp = Worksheets("3rd Pivot")
        
    ALastRow = fp.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("3rd Pivot").PivotTables("secondpivot_table").PivotCache.Refresh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wq As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("3rd Pivot")
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("secondpivot_table")
    Dim pF As PivotField
    Set pF = pt.PivotFields("Principal Vendor Name")
    pF.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    pF.CurrentPage = "(All)"
        
        
    For i = 1 To pF.PivotItems.Count
    k = i
    For j = 1 To pF.PivotItems.Count
    If i = j Then
    pF.PivotItems(i).Visible = True
    VendorNames(i) = pF.PivotItems(i).name
    a = pF.PivotItems(i).name
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
    wkb.SaveAs "E:\ARC master\" & a & ".xlsx"
    Else:
    pF.PivotItems(j).Visible = False
    End If
        Next j
        Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `For j = 1 To pF.PivotItems.Count` ?? No `Next j`... My point is that you should review your code again. You are missing quite a lot to make it run... End If, no declaration of i and j variable, missing next j etc....

Comment: yes i added after the next i still it is not resolved